# Greyscale image that is not in focus

Tags: html, css

I am new to html and CSS, bare with me. I got two images, the one that gets hovered on will get bigger and text will show. Now, i want the image that is not in focus to get grayscaled.
Also when neither of the images is hovered over, they're not having the grayscale effect on.

Is this possible through CSS?

Comment: Yes it is possible but please visit this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Understood, im a bit new..

Comment: share your code snippet here you can use https://codepen.io/ and share the link here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it can be achieved using pure CSS. Here's how

```css
.img1 {
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  background: #ff0000;
}
.img2 {
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  margin-left: 5rem;
  background: #ffff00;
}

.img1:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2); /* some other css that you want when hovered on img1 */
}

.img1:hover~.img2 { /* This selector selects img2 when img1 is hovered */
  /* Here I have used the sibling selector which selects the sibling next to image 1 you could have also used direct sibling selector with + sign instead of ~. But of course, you can achieve this behavior with different selectors*/
  filter: grayscale(80%); /* makes image grey */
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="img1" src="https://static.remove.bg/remove-bg-web/8fb1a6ef22fefc0b0866661b4c9b922515be4ae9/assets/start_remove-c851bdf8d3127a24e2d137a55b1b427378cd17385b01aec6e59d5d4b5f39d2ec.png" alt="">
  <img class="img2" src="https://static.remove.bg/remove-bg-web/8fb1a6ef22fefc0b0866661b4c9b922515be4ae9/assets/start_remove-c851bdf8d3127a24e2d137a55b1b427378cd17385b01aec6e59d5d4b5f39d2ec.png" alt="">
<div>
```

You can do it other way round to change img1 when hovered on img2.

Comment: This won't work. 1: `img2` is a sibling to `img1`, not a descendent. You'd have to use one of the sibling selectors (`+`/`~`). 2: It can't achieve the desired effect when hovering over `img2` because sibling selectors only selects subsequent elements, not preceding ones.

Comment: Yes, actually I forgot to add the sibling selector in a hurry. But I have modified the code and added the snippet and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a combination of `:hover` on the container and on the images you can.

```css
.container {
  width: fit-content;
}

.container img {
  transition: 0.5s filter ease-in-out, 0.5s transform ease-in-out;
  margin-inline: 1rem;
}

.container:hover img {
  filter: grayscale(1);
}

.container:hover img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/1/150/150" alt="">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/2/150/150" alt="">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/3/150/150" alt="">
</div>
```